# how to take screenshots of virtual box

Tags: webos

how to take screenshots of palm emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always take screenshots natively. orange + sym + s i believe (not sure what keys they are in emulator, but those are ones on the phone). you can then send that photo to wherever.

Comment: The "sym" key is not available in the emulator. http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1744#Emulator-KeyboardShortcutsEmulator

Answer (score 1):

We use [HyperSnap 6](http://www.hyperionics.com/) for all our screen capture needs. It's quite capable of capturing screen information inside a VMWare guest from the actual host machine and I suspect it would have little trouble with a Palm emulator as well, since it basically operates at the host level.

You can easily capture dynamic ranges (where you use the mouse/keyboard to mark top-left and bottom-right corners) as well as pre-specified ranges like "same range as last time" or "the current window" with simple key combinations (this last one is ideal for our demo and documentation purposes).

One other nice feature is the fact that it's like a mini-paint program (actually, it's a lot better than MSPaint) which allows us to highlight important bits of the image with markers and such, before saving.

Sorry to sound like an advert, but you *did* ask :-)

Comment: Agreed, just use a system-level screen capture. Print Screen, Grab, Cmd-Shift-4, whatever is available on your host.